# Glide 3.8.0 has duplicated image in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I use glide in my `RecyclerView` adapter, when I scroll it fast, usually, there is some item with duplicate image there. But it doesn't happen when I scroll it slowly.

Here is my gradle.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

Here is my bindViewHolder

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(holder instanceof NewsViewHolder) {
            NewsViewHolder newsViewHolder = (NewsViewHolder) holder;
            final Article article = articleList.get(position);

            newsViewHolder.tvName.setText(article.getTitle());
            newsViewHolder.tvDescription.setText(article.getDescription());
            ImageLoaderHelper.getImageFromUrl(article.getUrlToImage(), newsViewHolder.ivImage, signatureCache);

            newsViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    onNewsItemClickListener.onNewsItemClick(article);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is my helper

```
public class ImageLoaderHelper {

    public static void getImageFromUrl(String url, final ImageView imageView, String signature) {
        if(url != null && !url.equals("")) {
            Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
                    .load(url)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .signature(new StringSignature(signature.trim()))
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                        }
                    });
        }
        else {
            Glide.clear(imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    }
}
```

And then the imageview

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/ivImage"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Any solution for this one?

Comment: If the `ImageView` corrects itslef then you can try an *ImageHolder* some default image (or null) while the image is being loaded.

Comment: I have tried put this imageView.setImageBitmap(null) before if(url != null && !url.equals("")) { but it's still happening

Comment: Try setting .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image) .error(R.drawable.placeholder_image) in glide bulder.

Comment: It still duplicated when I scroll it fast

Comment: What does `duplicate image` mean?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.error(R.drawable.no_image);
Glide.with(context).setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load(ApiInterface.Image_URL_Local +
              recentViewModels.get(position).getImagePath()).into(holder.binding.ivProductImage);
```

inside your onBindViewHolder in adapter